# reactnative keep elements layout when user changes font size

Tags: react-native, font-size

Is there a way on react-native to keep some expected layout of elements when the user changes the font size at a system level?

So, for example, the user changes larger font settings for visually impaired style.

But then my layout goes out of control.

[image: changed font size]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can restrict the system font size effect on your app font-size.
There will be two ways to do this:

First you can strictly disable the font size from changing with system font changes.
   Add the following code to your Parent component constructor.  (like App.js)

```
Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

Second way is by setting the `maxFontSizeMultiplier` in your App,js

```
Text.defaultProps = {};
Text.defaultProps.maxFontSizeMultiplier = 1.4 // number you can specify
```

It will scale maximum to 1.3 times of the original font.

For more detail you can refer [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#maxfontsizemultiplier)

Hope this will help.